# Delete children component vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have some components created by a v-for, I want to delete a component with the next component:

`this.products.$remove(this.currentproduct);`

I get the next error: "Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null"

¿Any ideas?, I try with $destroy() inside the component adn I can't.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this accessing to the component variable, and dot, and method.

From the parent to the child:

```
// Access to destroy child method
<br>
this.$children[index].destroyElement();
```

Child:

```
// It destroy the component
destroyElement(){
    // Destroy method
    this.$destroy();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice`:

```
this.products.splice(this.products.indexOf(this.currentproduct), 1);
```

**[UPDATE]**

See example bellow:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
  },
  methods: {
    removeItem: function (item) {
      this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
      {{ item }}
      
      <button type="button" v-on:click="removeItem(item)">x</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the code and I got this message:
Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null.

I have this code for my components:

<div v-for="product in products">
<product :product="product" :currentproduct.sync="currentproduct" inline-template :delete_index.sync="$index"> TODO </product>

Comment: Publish your code on jsfiddle and past the link here.

Answer (score -1):

Use v-if with a flag on child component

```
<child-component v-if="flag"></child-component>
```